# Failure to start the Start Zeppelin

Tags: hadoop, apache-zeppelin

When I start the Start Zeppelin after 3 trials, I get the following error message:
Failed to start Zeppelin.service: Unit Zeppelin.service failed to load: No such file or directory
If I try to run Open Zeppelin I get some additional errors.

Comment: Did you started Zeppelin three times without stopping after each start? What do the logs files say?

Comment: I restated my machine before each time.